# It didn't have to be that good but it was/ it is?

Tags: word-usage

I saw a really good video a couple of hours ago and if I were to describe it to someone would I use 'it didn't have to be that good but it is or it didn't have to be that good but it was'?
Also can someone tell me if what I wrote is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> It didn't have to be that good but it was.

is the correct one.

By the rules of [reported speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirect_speech) you need to match the second verb to the tense of the first one.

Comment: Thank you. So even if it's still good it has to be was?

Comment: Yes. If you wanted to use present tense, then the first verb should also be in present, like this: "It doesn't have to be that good but it is."

Comment: ok now i get it. Thank you for replying quickly